# Shorter/more efficient way of writing a link function that adds new elements in lexicographical order

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

Attempting an exercise in programming principles and practice text, I spent a while debugging till I eventually managed to write a working code for the function. The exercise started like this:
I created template class for the Link:

```
template<typename T>
struct Link
{
    T val;
    Link* prev;
    Link* succ;

    Link(const T& value, Link* p = nullptr, Link* s = nullptr)
        :val{value},prev {p}, succ{ s } {}

    Link* add_ordered_(Link*);
};
```

Then the tough part was to implement the `add_ordered_(Link*)` function such that every time I add a new element using (new), the Link follows a lexicographical order. So this was my long shot at it:

```
template<typename T >
Link<T>* Link<T>::add_ordered_(Link<T>*n)
{
    if (n == nullptr)return this;
    if (this == nullptr)return n;

    if (n->val < this->val)
    {
        Link* temp = this->prev;
        if (temp == nullptr)
        {
            if (this->prev)
            {
                this->prev->succ = n;
            }
            n->prev = this->prev;
            this->prev = n;
            n->succ = this;
            return this;
        }
        while (n->val < temp->val && temp)
        {
            if (temp->prev == nullptr)
            {
                if (temp->prev)
                {
                    temp->prev->succ = n;
                }
                n->prev = temp->prev;
                temp->prev = n;
                n->succ = temp;
                return this;
            }
            temp = temp->prev;
            if (n->val > temp->val)
            {
                n->prev = temp;
                if (temp->succ) temp->succ->prev = n;
                n->succ = temp->succ;
                temp->succ = n;
                return this;
            }
            if (temp->prev == nullptr)
            {
                if (temp->prev)
                {
                    temp->prev->succ = n;
                }
                n->prev = temp->prev;
                temp->prev = n;
                n->succ = temp;
                return this;
            }
        }

        if (this->prev)
        {
            this->prev->succ = n;
        }
        n->prev = this->prev;
        this->prev = n;
        n->succ = this;
        return this;
    }
    else
    {
        n->prev = this;
        if (this->succ)this->succ->prev = n;
        n->succ = this->succ;
        this->succ = n;
        return n;
    }
}
```

I used a print_link function to print out the elements for easy debugging:

```
template<typename T>
void print_link(Link<T>* x)
{
    while (x)
    {
        cout << x->val << endl;
        x = x->prev;
    }
}
```

Tested it like this:

```
int main()
{
     Link<int>*numbers = new Link<int>{ 5 };
     numbers = numbers->add_ordered_(new Link<int> {7} );
     numbers = numbers->add_ordered_( new Link<int>{3} );
     numbers = numbers->add_ordered_(new Link<int>{ 25 });
     numbers = numbers->add_ordered_(new Link<int>{ 19 });
     numbers = numbers->add_ordered_(new Link<int>{ 22 });
     numbers = numbers->add_ordered_(new Link<int>{ 16 });
     numbers = numbers->add_ordered_(new Link<int>{ 44 });
     numbers = numbers->add_ordered_(new Link<int>{ 11 });
     numbers = numbers->add_ordered_(new Link<int>{ 37 });
     print_link(numbers);
     cout << endl;  
     delete[] numbers;
}
```

The output being:

```
44
37
25
22
19
16
11
7
5
3
```

The `add_ordered_` function I wrote seems to be too long, ugly and inefficient. I would like it if someone shows me a more efficient way of writing it.

Comment: `if (this == nullptr)`. Cannot happen (except in UB case).

Comment: Split your method in 2 parts: find position where to insert. insert at position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your method:

```
std::pair<Link*, Link*> find_neighbor(const Link& link) {
    // assert(prev == nullptr);
    Link* left = nullptr; // == prev
    Link* right = this;

    while (right && right->val < link.val) {
        left = right;
        right = right->succ;
    }
    return {left, right};
}

void insert_between(Link* left, Link* right)
{
    prev = left;
    succ = right;
    if (left) {
        left->succ = this;   
    }
    if (right) {
        right->prev = this;   
    }
}

Link* add_ordered_(Link* link)
{
    // assert(prev == nullptr); // Assume we call it only with first element
    if (link == nullptr) {
        return this;   
    }
    auto p = find_neighbor(*link);
    link->insert_between(p.first, p.second);
    if (prev) {
        return prev; // == link
    }
    return this;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/OEEC0P)

Comment: Thanks. Was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It's often a good idea to break things down into smaller parts that are simple.

Let's add 2 more functions to your class, `add_after` and `add_before`.

```
template<typename T>
Link<T>* Link<T>::add_after(Link<T>*n)
{
    if (succ) {
        n->succ = succ;
    }

    succ = n;
    n->prev = this;
}

template<typename T>
Link<T>* Link<T>::add_before(Link<T>*n)
{
    if (prev) {
        n->prev = prev;
    }

    prev = n;
    n->succ = this;
}
```

Now with these two handy guys ready, we can go ahead and re-write `add_odered_` where we just need to focus on finding the right place to insert.

```
template<typename T >
Link<T>* Link<T>::add_ordered_(Link<T>*n)
{
    Link* insert = this;
    if (n->val > insert->val) {
        insert->add_before(n);
        return n;
    }

    while (n->val < insert->val && insert->succ)
        insert = insert->succ;

    if (n->val > insert->val)
        insert->add_before(n);
    else
        insert->add_after(n);

    return this;
}
```